# Error in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a error with this :

```
#myview
<h2><%=link_to "Controller Enable/Disable", Controller_Enable_path %></h2>

#routes.rb
 match '/Controller_Enable', to:'static_pages#Controller_Enable', via: 'get'

#controller
def Controller_Enable
        puts "Controller_Enable.................................."
    end
```

And it show "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Controller_Enable_path", I don't know how to correct this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the method name in small letters: `controller_enable`. Capitalized names are recognized as constants.

It should be like this:

```
#myview
<h2><%=link_to "Controller Enable/Disable", controller_enable_path %></h2>

#routes.rb
 match '/controller_enable', to:'static_pages#controller_enable', via: 'get'

#controller
def controller_enable
  puts "controller_enable.................................."
end
```